# The formation of shockwave inside pellets in inertial confinement fusion

Tags: energy, fusion, nuclear-engineering

In the explanations i have read on the internet about ICF they all explain that the top layer of the pellet or the ablator is heated till it explodes and this produces a reaction force which compress the D+T fuel. They then say shock waves are formed due to the collapsing fuel which compress it even further and eventually ignite the fuel. My question is why and when are the shock waves formed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hydrodynamics shocks are caused by steep changes in pressure over short periods of time.  In ICF in general, pressure is applied during ablation (the reaction force you mention).  This ablation pressure is related to the driver (e.g., laser intensity).

For example, in direct-drive ICF, the ablation pressure scales as $I^{2/3}$, where $I$ is the laser intensity.  Typical pulse durations are a few nanoseconds and may consist, for example, of a steep rise in intensity, a flat-top region on the order of a few nanoseconds, followed by a sharp drop in intensity (a step up and a step down).  Sometimes this square pulse is shaped to customize the pressure profile and control how shocks are launched.  Sometimes it is even preceded by several short-duration bursts of laser intensity ("pickets") to control shock timing and coalescence.

Shockwaves launched into the pellet compress and heat the shell; they also set the fuel adiabat.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where i might be able to find more about how the laser intensity is varied to produce different shock waves and why they are varied?

Comment: @IntentFileters Stefano Atzeni has a good book on ICF (ISBN-10: 0199568014).  Keep in mind that shock timing is a hot research topic.  So there are lots of research papers out there.  Zel'dovich and Raizer have an advanced book on shockwaves in general (ISBN-10: 0486420027).  V. Goncharov has done a lot of theoretical work on this in recent years and has a lot of research papers out there on the fine details and the most up-to-date theory.